# Change Windows 10 profile picture separately from outlook.com/Mircrosoft account

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-account, outlook.com

My Windows 10 user profile is linked with my Microsoft account. I would like to set my profile picture for the account independently from the rest of my Microsoft account. Right now, when I attempt to set a profile picture in Windows, it updates my Microsoft account to use the same picture. Is my only option to unlink the profile from the Microsoft account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove your picture from Outlook.com. I do that and have a picture for my computer Microsoft Account. Otherwise, if you want picture both places then they are the same.

Comment: That's a decent workaround. I'm willing to go with that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks and good luck with your profile pictures